# TextArea изменить цвет при наведении мышкой (Css стили)

Tags: css, javafx

есть какой-то не примечательный TextArea (который нельзя изменять), хочу чтобы при наведении на него мышкой, область изменялась в черный цвет, а текст в нём в белый.

делаю вот так:

```
.text-area :hover .content {
-fx-background-color: black;
-fx-text-fill:white;
}
.text-area :hover{
-fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

вот что выходит:

когда мышка вне TextArea
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

когда мышка в нем [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.text-area:hover {
    -fx-control-inner-background: black;
}
```